# SharePoint - Employee Directory

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to Create a Employee directory in SharePoint online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the blogs and videos related to the employee directory collaboration project : https://blog.hyperfish.com/employee-directory-in-office-365-and-sharepoint-

I would be carefull about building on Delve as it seems like MS Search might replace Delve in the future ( just my take on the info from MS)

Another option could be to use the PnP Search web parts and build your own version: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/tree/master/solutions/ModernSearch/react-search-refiners